# How to binding image to repeater control from sql server image field in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i am storing the images into database directly. Now i want to bind the repeater control to the database's image field. I want to load all the images from the database.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Nimesh you can use following way to create image from byte array and bind to repetor

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookName") %>
<hr>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookDescription") %>
<td width="100px">
<p align="left">
 <img src= '<%# GetImageFromByte(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image")) %>'  
 alt="" style="height:200px;width:200px;border:1px solid gray;"/>
</td>
</p>
```

---

```
//////////////////////// ////////////////////////////    
call  GetImageFromByte  this function from aspx as shown above and convert byte array to image and save in folder then return complete image path 

public string GetImageFromByte(object byt)
 {
  byte[] byts = Convert.ToByte(byt);
  return byteArrayToImage(byts);
}

private string byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
  System.Drawing.Image newImage;
  string strFileName = "Filder path where image need to store " + "yourfilename.gif";
  if (byteArrayIn != null)
   {
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
     {
       newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
       newImage.Save(strFileName);
       img.Attributes.Add("src", strFileName);
     }
   lblMessage.Text = "The image conversion was successful.";
  }
  else
  {
    Response.Write("No image data found!");
  }
     return "Filder path where image need to store " + "yourfilename.gif";
 }
```

Comment: thanks rahul.deshmukh

Comment: What if multiple requests are being served
at the same time and they are all trying to write the same file?

Answer (score 1):

Passing a byte stream which holds the images is not the correct way of doing this in asp.net.
The best way to show images is to save the image on the server and only pass the link to the image (using an `asp:Image` control for instance)...

In your case you have 2 options I guess:

1. Refactor the application to save the images on the Hard Disk, and only store the URL to the image as a text field in the DB.
2. When you get a request and want to show an image, save the image to a temporary directory on your server and then pass the URL to that temporary image file to the client.