# How to load image into a repeater control from sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

How can i load an image into A Image control from sql database from sql server?
The image is stored in image format...
Image control is in repeater
Code in repeater

```
<table id="tableposts" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 80%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbpostusername" runat="server" 
                Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>'>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="posthead" runat="server" 
                Text='<%#Eval("PostHead") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p id="postcontent"><%#Eval("PostContent") %></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Image ID="postimage" runat="server" ImageUrl=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code to retrieve values

```
private DataSet GetData()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginConString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select PostID,UserName,PostHead,PostContent,PostImage from Posts WHERE USERID ='" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    postids = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: CHECK THE BELOW LINK


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108729/how-to-binding-image-to-repeater-control-from-sql-server-image-field-in-asp-net

Comment: Getting An error  Convert.ToByte(byt); cannot convert byte to byte[]

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
public string GetImageFromByte(object byt)
 {
   byte[] byts = (byte[])byt;
   return byteArrayToImage(byts);
 }
```

Instead of

```
   public string GetImageFromByte(object byt)
      {
         byte[] byts = Convert.ToByte(byt);
         return byteArrayToImage(byts);
      }
```

Comment: not it throws an error that postimage doesn't exist in the current context